# How do I compare two columns in the same table?

Tags: sql

I would like to compare two columns in the same table.  I want to be able to return all rows where the two columns have the same value.

I am looking for something like `SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE C1 = C4`.

Therefore in the example below I would return only the first row:

```
C1    || C2  || C3  || C4
--------------------------
1     || a   || b   || 1
2     || a   || b   || 4
3     || b   || d   || 2
4     || b   || d   || 2
```

If it matters, I am using `SQLite` (more specifically `WebSQL`).

Comment: SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE C1 = C4 should work.  Does it not?  If not, are they the same data type and length?  You may need to convert.  I don't know about WebSql, but I've seen some db systems that refuse to match if one is a varchar(5) and the other is a varchar(10) even though they hold the same value.  In those systems you have to use Convert(varchar, 10, FieldName) to get a match.

Comment: @DavidStratton how embarassing!  It works perfectly.  I was trying to wrap selects in where clauses.  Dumbest question so far.

Comment: NOt at all.  We all do things like that.

Comment: You took the time to answer me. Please by all means chalk it up as an answer. You were completely correct. Maybe it will stop someone else making the same mistake as I have!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE C1 = C4` should work. Does it not?

If not, are they the same data type and length? You may need to convert.

I don't know about WebSql, but I've seen some db systems that refuse to match if one is a varchar(5) and the other is a varchar(10) even though they hold the same value. 
In those systems you have to use something like

```
 Convert(varchar, 10, FieldName)
```

to get a match.