# How to compare two columns in the same table

Tags: oracle

First this is how my table looks like:

```
tbl
------------------------------------------
|  USERID           |     requestID       
|test1@gmail.com    |  sunsun@gmail.com
|sunsun@gmail.com   |  test1@gmail.com
|test2@gmail.com    |  kittyhsk@gmail.com
|sunsun@gmail.com   |  test2@gmail.com
|test@gmail.com     |  sunsun@gmail.com
|sunsun@gmail.com   |  test3@gmail.com
```

I named my columns wrong but 
userIds are the ids that are following requestIds,
and requestIds are the ids that are being followed.

What I want to do is to find the cases that the ids are following each other.

Like for example, I log in with the id sunsun@gmail.com(this is not real address), then I find ids that I'm following and also the ids that follows me, but under the ids that are following each other, I want to print out some text saying that they are following each other. (So under test1 and test2, I should have that text.)

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245440/how-do-i-compare-two-columns-in-the-same-table)  but this does not really apply to my situation as I have to get the results under one logged in ID.

I was trying to do this by myself but I'm all out of ideas. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From your given data, `test2` doesn't seem to be following `sunsun@gmail.com`. But considering that is also an entry in your dataset, @karina's answer would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to join the table with itself and compare. So something like

```
SELECT *
FROM table as t1
JOIN table as t2
ON t1.requestid = t2.useriD and t1.userid = t2.requestid
```

Comment: Thank you! I heard it's called self join but I'm still not familiar with it. Anyway thanks.